# Use an array to populate a listbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

The website I am working on will contain a drop-down list that shows a number of reason codes.

Is it possible to populate a drop-down list with an array derived from a custom class?

Something like this:

**ASPX Page**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlReasonsWhy" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

**ASPX Code Behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //instantiate custom class
    Class1 reasonsList = new Class1();
   //populate reasons list
   this.ddlReasonsWhy.Items.Add(reasonsList.getReasons);
```

**Custom Class**

```
public string[] getReasons()
    {
        string[] Reasons;
        Reasons[0] = "test";
        Reasons[1] = "test2";
        Reasons[2] = "test3";

        return Reasons;
    }
```

***UPDATE1:***

Thanks to the answers and this stack [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132643/adding-listitems-to-a-dropdownlist-from-a-generic-list) my final solution is similar to Ahmet and silky answers.

**Class**

```
 public List<ListItem> getRejectReasons()
    {
        List<ListItem> reasons = new List<ListItem>();
        reasons.Add(new ListItem("Select Value", "0"));
        reasons.Add(new ListItem("Red", "1"));
        reasons.Add(new ListItem("Green", "2"));
        return reasons;

    }
```

**Code Behind**

```
 //instantiate custom class
 Class1 reject = new Class1();
 this.ddlReasonsWhy.DataSource = reject.getRejectReasons();
 this.ddlReasonsWhy.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ***ListItem*** instead of *string* and ***Addrange*** for *Add*

edit: getReasons is not a variable so use getReasons()

ASPXPAGE

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlReasonsWhy" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

ASPX Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //instantiate custom class
    Class1 reasonsList = new Class1();
   //populate reasons list
   this.ddlReasonsWhy.Items.AddRange(reasonsList.getReasons());
}
```

Custom Class

```
public ListItem[] getReasons()
    {
        ListItem[] Reasons;
        Reasons[0] = "test";
        Reasons[1] = "test2";
        Reasons[2] = "test3";

        return Reasons;
    }
```

Comment: thanks - this was very helpful - please see my update1 for the correct class syntax.

Answer (score 3):

-- Edit:

I've noticed you specifically wanted to bind to an array. I don't believe *that* is possible (may be wrong); I leave my example below of how to do it for a custom class, perhaps it is of use, perhaps not. Hopefully someone else answers you more directly.

-- Old:

Certainly it is, like so:

```
ddlList.DataSource     = yourDataSource;
ddlList.DataTextField  = "DisplayProperty";
ddlList.DataValueField = "PropertyForValue";
ddlList.DataBind();
```

But note, in your example you've not posted the class, you've posted a method. In the example about 'yourDataSource' should be something like:

```
List<YourObjects> yourDataSource = new List<YourObjects>();
```

Answer (score 1):

(untested)

```
this.ddlReasonsWhy.DataSource = reasonsList.getReasons;
this.ddlReasonsWhy.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but how about:

```
this.ddlReasonsWhy.Items.Add(reasonsList.getReasons().Select(r => new ListItem(r)));
```